# return level in non-stationary case using GPD (POT approach)

Tags: r, extreme-value

I'm doing some extreme value analysis, specifically, using a POT-approach and I'm trying to add some covariates to model excesses. Since I'm quite new in extremes, I'd like to ask for some help to determine the return level when using covariates. I did it in the case of stationary case, but I'm having problems when using non-stationary using the R package **extRemes**:

```
 # Stationary
 f1 <- fevd(value, mydata, threshold = 100, type = "GP", 
            time.units = "122/year", span = 23)
 return.level(f1, return.period = 10)
 # Covariate-scale function
 f2 <- fevd(value,mydata, scale.fun = ~bl_PV, threshold = 100, 
            type = "GP", time.units = "122/year", span = 23)
```

In the second case f2, the output looks like:

```
fevd(x = value, data = st1, threshold = 100, scale.fun = ~bl_PV, 
     type = "GP", span = 23, time.units = "122/year")

[1] "Estimation Method used: MLE"


 Negative Log-Likelihood Value:  5489.483 


 Estimated parameters:
    sigma0     sigma1      shape 
27.7869544 11.7117531 -0.2793198 

 Standard Error Estimates:
   sigma0    sigma1     shape 
0.8560494 1.4317868 0.0139366 

 Estimated parameter covariance matrix.
             sigma0       sigma1         shape
sigma0  0.732820537 -0.018595517 -0.0093082321
sigma1 -0.018595517  2.050013404 -0.0055950344
shape  -0.009308232 -0.005595034  0.0001942288

 AIC = 10984.97 

 BIC = 11000.54
```

Since my covariate is binary, 0 or 1, I was trying to incorporate this information and get the return level when is 0 or 1, similarly than:

```
  v <- make.qcov(fit2, vals = list(sigma1 = c(0, 1)))
```

But I'm struggling to use to function `return.level` with "v", since I'm not sure how to set qcov here. Or if there would be another way (or function) to compute the return level in the non-stationary case.

Any idea will be very helpful,

Thanks.